# SASS пребор в цикле hsl цвета

Tags: css3, sass, scss, map

Подскажите, как правильно написано SCSS для перебора цветов с псевдоэлементами. мой SCSS

```css
$s: 84%;
$l: 54%;

$pictureBlock: (

        color1: 234,
        color2: 209,
        color3: 191,
        color4: 140,
        color5: 86,
        color6: 57,
        color7: 46,
        color8: 33,
        color9: 20,
        color10: 359
);

@for $i from 1 through 10 {
.work_place__label:nth-child(#{$i}){
        background-color: hsl( #{map-get($pictureBlock,'color'+$i)}, $s, $l);
  }
}
```

но он не отрабатывает